# Handling an ajax return array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

This is the ajax part that i think is causing the problem:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./php/censusdata2.php",
        success: function (data) 
        {
            createMarker($list.data.lat, $list.data.lng, map, $list.data.FORENAME);
        }   
    });
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function createMarker(lat, lng, map, title)
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: title
        });
    marker.setMap(map);

    markers.push(marker);
    }
```

It is getting it's data from here:

```
$list=array();  
        foreach ($s as $row):

        $data = new stdClass(); // create a new object
        $data->lat=htmlspecialchars($row['lat'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data->lng=htmlspecialchars($row['lng'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data->FORENAME=htmlspecialchars($row['FORENAME'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data->SURNAME=htmlspecialchars($row['SURNAME'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        array_push($list,$data); // push object to stack array
        endforeach;
    echo json_encode($list);
```

This is the response taken from 'Developer tools- Network- censusdata2 - response'

> [{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Ellen","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Beckett"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"William","SURNAME":"Beckett"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henretta","SURNAME":"Wetheral"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mark","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Robert
>   John","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Lizzie","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary
>   L","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Anne","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Joseph","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Patrick","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Susan","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henry","SURNAME":"Johnstone"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George
>   Hy","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"William","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Ann
>   Jane","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Elizabeth","SURNAME":"McCann"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Charlotte","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Joseph","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Selina","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Anna","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Eliza","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Rachiel","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Eliza","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Robert","SURNAME":"Nisbet"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Bowen"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Elizabeth","SURNAME":"Bowen"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Margaret","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henry","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"McGarrell"}]

Comment: the markers that i thought would appear on my map didn't

Comment: Why you don't use $.each(data, function(v){ createmarker(...); });

Comment: because I don't know how to, i don't know what "$.each(data, function(v){ createmarker(...); });" means. Does it go in the success: function (data) bit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: There is no "map" in your posted code... what does your initialize function look like?

Comment: All your points are at the same location.  Not very useful...

Comment: var markers = [];
var map;
     
function initialize()
{
             
var mapOptions = 
{
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.408, -6.292),
zoom: 8
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),mapOptions);
            
$.ajax
({

Comment: `i don't know what "$.each(data, function(v){ createmarker(...); });" means` Try the documentation: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `success` callback, you never loop over the array of data.  Instead, you are trying to create one marker from an array of points.

Instead of

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "./php/censusdata2.php",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        createMarker($list.data.lat, $list.data.lng, map, $list.data.FORENAME);
    }   
});
```

Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "./php/censusdata2.php",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        $.each(data,function(index,point){
            createMarker(point.lat, point.lng, map, point.FORENAME);
        });
    }   
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB9za/)

Comment: Thank you but that is having the same problem, now the map isn't showing up at all.

Comment: What javascript errors are you getting?  That concept works for me, see the working fiddle I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(i,v) { 
     createMarker(v.lat, v.lng, map, v.FORENAME);
});
```

This should run for each marker you got..
Put it inside the `success: function(data) { ....... }`

Comment: OK this is what i'v got now  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./php/censusdata2.php",
        success: function (data) 
         {
          $.each(data, function(i,v) { 
          createMarker(v.lat, v.lng, map, v.FORENAME);
          });
         }   
         }); and the map isn't showing up now

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that puts your points on a map.  See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/ER92u/

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(54.508869, -6.292547);

    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);
    $.each(points,function(index,point){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: point.FORENAME
        });
    });
});

var points = [{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Ellen","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Beckett"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"William","SURNAME":"Beckett"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henretta","SURNAME":"Wetheral"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mark","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Robert John","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Lizzie","SURNAME":"Wetherall"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary L","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Anne","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Joseph","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Thompson"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Annie","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Patrick","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"John","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Susan","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henry","SURNAME":"Johnstone"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George Hy","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"William","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Ann Jane","SURNAME":"Helles"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Elizabeth","SURNAME":"McCann"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Charlotte","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Joseph","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Murray"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"George","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Selina","SURNAME":"Gribben"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Sarah","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Anna","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Eliza","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Rachiel","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Eliza","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"Mulholland"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Robert","SURNAME":"Nisbet"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Thomas","SURNAME":"Bowen"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Elizabeth","SURNAME":"Bowen"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Margaret","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Henry","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"James","SURNAME":"O'Hara"},{"lat":"54.508869","lng":"-6.292547","FORENAME":"Mary","SURNAME":"McGarrell"}];
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #map {
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;
 }
```

Of course, only one marker will be visible due to all the points having the same set of coordinates.

Comment: Yea , that's great but how do I get the data into the var points= from the censusdata2?

Comment: That was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24394005/943730 It is your job to put the two together ;)

Comment: Thank you all, my problem is now fixed ,  managed to delete a curly brace ... I used $.each(data,function(index,point)
{            createMarker(point.lat, point.lng, map, point.FORENAME);

Comment: Great! Now you have just to mark the correct answer, if there is one.